# Build and Push Docker Image to Docker Hub- UnAuthorised

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

I have a git repository from where I am trying to build and publish a docker image to docker hub.
Some how I am keep on getting Unauthorised for docker login step.

Any Help is appreciated.

GitHub Repo : https://github.com/Git-Beginner/ghaction/actions

Comment: Can you use those Secrets in any other way? I mean are you sure they are correct? Your Action `echo secrets` obviously only prints masked values (btw. you should never echo secrets anywhere, that's why GitHub masks them in the echo output).

Answer (score 1):

You should first login to docker hub by typing the command `docker login` it will prompt the user name and after that password of docker hub after that try pushing the image again to docker hub

Answer (score 0):

I am not that sure if this is what you have asked for but in order to push images to docker hub , first you need to build your docker image. then create a repository on docker hub with the name you want. and then do something like this

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t nametoyourlocalimage:version .    //this will build your docker image locally
docker tag nametoyourlocalimage:version YourDockerHubNewReporUrlYouJUstCreated

docker login  //this will prompt you to enter your username and password
docker push YourDockerHubNewRepoUrlYouJUstCreated
docker logout
```

Comment: This has been resolved, i used the actions instead using the direct command commands. Thanks  for responding all.